# javascript add 1ms to a string date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, milliseconds

I have a `var` in js which is represented like so: 
`"lastTimeModified": "2019-02-26T11:38:20.222Z"`

and I want to add to it `1ms`

I have tried something like this:

```
dateObj = new Date();
dateObj.setMilliseconds(1);
var newDate = lastTimeModified + dateObj
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm curious, what's the use case? If you're trying to use datetimes as unique identifiers, that is bound to fail.

Comment: @johnDvorak I have records in my db, and I need to add 1ms to all of them

Comment: But why do you need to add 1ms to all of them?

Comment: @JohnDvorak something related to business logic. that specific field needs to be updated by 1ms

Answer (score 3):

If you can get your date in milliseconds than you can directly add 1 millisecond to it

```
var date = new Date(lastTimeModified)    // convert string to date object
var mill = date.getMilliseconds()        // Get millisecond value from date
mill += 1                                // Add your one millisecond to it
date.setMilliseconds(mill)               // convert millisecond to again date object
```

Comment: `date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + 1)` is a little less to type. :-)

Comment: @RobG true. I didn't knew about these methods! Thanks for update :)

Answer (score 0):

The below takes your time string turns it into a date object, gets the milliseconds since the 1. of January 1970 adds 1ms and turns it back into a date object

```
var newDate = new Date(new Date(lastTimeModified).getTime() + 1)
```